# How to test if requests increase metrics while not getting any response in Vert.x?

Tags: java, rx-java2, vert.x, junit5, micrometer

Job of my Vert.x server, when it gets some invalid requests, is to NOT send any resposne back, but only increase associated metric. How can I test it?

The following code don't work, because as we never get the response back, the handler's code never is executed - I've just posted it to show you what I want in my test.

```
@Test
void invalidUrlTest(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) {
    HttpRequest<String> request = WebClient
            .create(vertx, this.webClientOptions)
            .get(8080, "localhost", "/someinvalidaddress/")
            .as(BodyCodec.string());
    request.send(s -> {assertThat(meterRegistry.counter("invalid.request.counter")).isEqualTo(1.0);
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why your handle is not called (maybe your test is falling trough due missing ctx.async() ?) But in any case you can try to use the httpClient for your call and set an exceptionhandler when you make your assertion:

```
@Test
void invalidUrlTest(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext ctx) {
    Async async = ctx.async();
    HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();
    client.get(8080,"localhost","/someinvalidaddress/")
      .exceptionHandler(ex -> {
        assertThat(meterRegistry.counter("invalid.request.counter")).isEqualTo(1.0);
        async.complete();
      }).end();
}
```

Comment: My server logic is as follows: if it get right requests, it send back some response. If it get invalid request, it does not send back any request.

As I understand, the handler is invoked only after some response is received. But in my case, if request is invalid, the response never comes, so the handler is never invoked - that's the anser to your qustion, at least I believe it works that way :-)

Comment: in that case, the easiest way is to set a timeout on the request. That way when the timeout is reached, you end up in the exceptionhandler. client.get(...).setTimeout()